# Let $p$ be prime and $n\mid p-1$. Let $gcd(a,p)=1$, and $a^{(p-1)/n} \equiv 1 \mod p$. Show that there are $n$ solutions to $x^n \equiv a \mod p$.

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

> Let $p$ be prime and $n$ divide $p-1$. Let $gcd(a,p)=1$, and $a^{(p-1)/n} \equiv 1 \mod p$. Show that there are $n$ solutions to $x^n \equiv a \mod p$ for $x$ if $a$ is a constant.

For now I have come up with that there are $p-1$ solutions to $x^{p-1} \equiv 1 \mod p$

Answer (score 2):

Let $g $ be a primitive root modulo $p$ and $u\in\Bbb Z $ such that $a=g^u $.

By assumption, there exists an integer $m $ such that $p-1=nm $.

From $a^m\equiv 1\pmod p $ follows $mu\equiv 0\pmod {mn} $, hence there exists an integer $v $ such that $u=vn $.

If $x=g^y $, then we have $x^n\equiv a\pmod p $ if and only if $yn\equiv u\pmod {mn} $, that's $y\equiv v\pmod m$.
Consequently, $x^{v+km }$ for $0\leq k\leq n-1$ are the required $n $ solutions.

Comment: What is Fxp? Thanks.

Comment: Is a generator also called a primitive root?

Comment: Fxp is the name of collection of generator units, right?

Comment: @kai: I mean primitive root modulo $p $, I edit my answer.

Comment: Is it x=g^y (mod p), or x=g^y?

Comment: I don't quite get the last step.

Comment: Nevermind. I got it.

Comment: It is g^(v+km), I think.

Comment: It is $x^{v+km} $, because $x=g^y $ with $y\equiv v\pmod m$ that's $y=v+km $.

Comment: $(g^{v+km})^{n}=g^{nv+kmn}=g^{u+k(p-1)}=g^u=a$ (mod p)